# Implement custom Deserializer with default Serializer in Serde Rust?

Tags: rust, serde

When implementing custom `Deserialize` for some `struct`, it is no longer possible to use default `Serialize` as follows:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize, de::Error};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(remote = "Self")]
struct MyStruct {
    name: String,

    #[serde(default)]
    friend: bool,

    #[serde(default)]
    friend_name: Option<String>
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyStruct {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let this = Self::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        
        if this.friend && this.friend_name.is_none() {
            return Err(D::Error::custom("Must provide friend name if friend exist"));
        }
        
        Ok(this)
    }
}

fn main(){
    let json = r#"
        {
            "name": "MyName",
            "friend": true,
            "friend_name": "MyFriend"
        }
    "#;
    
    let me: MyStruct = serde_json::from_str::<MyStruct>(&json).unwrap();
    
    println!("{:?}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&me));
}
```

This gives the following Error:

```
|
42   |     println!("{:?}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&me));
     |                      ---------------------------- ^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `MyStruct`
     |                      |
     |                      required by a bound introduced by this call
```

Check [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=50a5aa8cabdc1a58884fc0a8d1725152)

Is there a way to specify the default `Serialize` with the custom `Deserialize`, or I need to implement `Serialize` myself ?

Comment: You should not use `#[serde(remote)]` here. Remove it and `#[derive(Deserialize)]` and it works (except, of course, that `Deserialize` recurses indefinitely).

Comment: I want to keep the custom `Deserialize` because I need to do some checks on the given fields, is there a way to do it without custom `Deserialize` ?

Comment: Of course keep it, remove the _derived_ `Deserialize`.

Comment: I rushed with the solution it is actually did not work, it generates a stack overflow, test it in Playground link

Comment: Check [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f8f41051d569054ac159fef5ea506dd) for the runtime stackoverflow error

Comment: As I said, this will cause an infinite recursion, since `deserialize()` calls `deserialize()` again.

Comment: Is there a solution for that?

Comment: You can always implement `Deserialize` manually. Or you can duplicate the struct definition, deserialize into that, validate then transform into the original struct. But IMHO, the best solution is to keep validation out of the deserialization. Parse, then validate.

Comment: In this case, however, the best idea seems to have a `Friend` struct, including `friend` and `friend_name`, and have `Option<Friend>` in `MyStruct`. This way, serde handles the validation for you.

Comment: OK, it doesn't seem to work as intended: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9e1a8023eb965f6782c34c611395006f.

Comment: I think validating input manually is better in this case.